# Using v-for in laravel + vue.js, am trying to display a table containing information of the user but nothing shows

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "OutPatient",
        data(){
            return{
                out_patients: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
                index(){
                        axios.get('/data/out_patient').then(({data}) =>
                                (this.out_patients = data.data));

                },
                update(){}
        },
        created(){
                this.index();
        }

    }
</script>



<tr v-for="out_patient in out_patients" v-bind:key="out_patient.id">
    <td>{{out_patient.id}}</td>
    <td>{{out_patient.first_name}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i></a>
      | 
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash red"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is my code but the data is not showing in the table even though in the XHR the data shows there.

In the inspect element I can see the data but the v-for loop is unable to display the data.

Comment: do you get the `out_patients` to your Vue component?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: the template is surrounded by a `<table>` tag, isn't it?

Comment: am not getting the out_patients to the Vue component and am not getting any error in the console

Comment: everything should work as expected. Despite the fact that you @Benjiro should provide a not-working example, I can provide you a working one: https://jsfiddle.net/dur5sf0k/ (I have simulated the network request via the setTimeout)

Comment: Try declaring `out_patients` as an array rather than an object (if you don't return a map structure)

Comment: please paste what you return in your Laravel controller

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you tried to extract data twice, you have this:

```
axios.get('/data/out_patient').then(({data}) =>
                                (this.out_patients = data.data));
```

if you already extract it here: `{data}` then you don't need `data.data`, only `data` below?

Answer (score 0):

```
index() {
                this.error = this.out_patients = null;
                this.loading = true;
                axios
                    .get('/data/out_patient')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.loading = false;
                        this.out_patients = response.data;
                    }).catch(error => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.error = error.response.data.message || error.message;
                });
            },
```

this rather works for me.
thank you all for the support

Answer (score 0):

can you try fetching the data on mounted life cycle hook instead of created in order to populate the table with data on page load mounted is the best hook lifecycle as much I know.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "OutPatient",
    data(){
        return{
            out_patients: {},
            out_patient:'',
        }
    },
    methods: {
           index(){
                 axios.get('/data/out_patient')
                     .then(({data}) =>
                         (this.out_patients = data.data));

           },
            update(){

            }
        },
    created(){
        this.index();
    }
}
</script>



<tr v-for="out_patient in out_patients" v-bind:key="out_patient.id">
    <td>{{out_patient.id}}</td>
    <td>{{out_patient.first_name}}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-edit blue"></i>
        </a>
        |
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-trash red"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Just declare ***out_patient*** in data. I hope this solves your issue.
And also check if ***out_patients*** is returning data.

Comment: `out_patient` should not be declared since it can cause confusion and malfunctioning

Comment: It works for me. I have also faced a similar issue. The above-mentioned solution works for me.

Comment: I have added the **out_patient** in the data but nothing is showing in the table

Comment: Please check value of out_patients obejct in console.

Comment: index(){
            var self = this;     axios.get('/data/out_patient')
                     .then((data)) =>
                         (self.out_patients = data.data));

           },

Comment: I added _console.log(self.out_patients)_ to the **created** function but in the console it says **undefined**

Comment: Where have you mentioned your routes. In web.php or api.php??